# Trying to return a conditional statement in program to search for an array element

Tags: c, pointers

I am writing a program to search an array element and return a conditional statement "Array element not found" if the entered element doesn't match any of the array elements.
I tried following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main()
{
    int a[100];
    int n,i,num;
    int *p=a;
    printf("Enter size of array:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter array elements:");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("Enter the element [%d]:",i);
        scanf("%d",p+i);
    }
    printf("Enter an element: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
        if (*(p+i)==num){
            printf("Array element Location is %d",i);
            break;
        }
        else{
            printf("Array element not found");
        }
        }
    }
```

But when an element not in the array is entered, the conditional statement "Array element not found" is printed n times as following:
[image]

My desired output is that the conditional statement should be printed just once if the array element is not found in the array.

Is there any different method I should try?

Comment: Instead of printing inside the loop, which will *always* print "found" or "not found" each iteration of the loop, set a variable to true or false. Then *after* the loop check that variable and print the result.

Comment: Please do not post images of code or output when properly-formatting text that you copy and paste would be perfectly fine.

Comment: @DavidGrayson I think that would help avoiding any confusion with my question and give reader the clear idea of what's going on.

Comment: Your screenshot is hard to read on a phone and it is difficult for search engines to index and doesn't provide any more useful information than the text would.

Comment: Alright. Noted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `break;` with `return 0;` to end the program.  Then move the line that prints "Array element not found" to be after the loop.  The loop body runs multiple times so of course "Array element not found" could be printed multiple times if you put it in the loop body.

Also put `\n` at end of your strings to add a line break so your program's output is readble.